# Use info from Input field in JS

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

So i am trying to assign a adress picked up from a input field to my JS script.

Whe code is as following:

```
<div class="input-group w-100 p-5">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="ipAdress">IP Adress:</span>
  </div>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ip adress" aria-label="ipAdress" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
 </div>
```

My script is as follows:

```
<script>
    function runFunc(funcName) {
        var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        httpRequest.open('GET', '/func.php?name=' + funcName);
        httpRequest.send();
    }
</script>
```

What i have tried to do:
As you can see i add the input as a variable and then assign the var to the httpRequest.open

```
<script>
    function runFunc(funcName) {
        var ipAdress = '';
        var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        httpRequest.open('GET', + ipAdress + '/func.php?name=' + funcName);
        httpRequest.send();
    }
</script>
```

Then in my mind it would lead to http://10.0.0.1/func.php?name=WhateverFunc
But i am obvisly wrong some where..

Comment: Any Error you are getting?

Comment: Yea, well not an error exactly but it tries to trigger the script locally. So the server 10.0.0.113 just trigger: http://10.0.0.113/func.php?name=WhateverFunc
And not http://10.0.0.1/func.php?name=WhateverFunc